# How can I deploy FastAPI manually on a Ubuntu Server?

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a very simple API (2 routes) which just has GET requests, and doesnt need any authentication or anything for now.

I want to know what is the best and appropariate way to deploy my API for production. I am unable to use docker, and would like to do it the server way.

So i have a few questions:

- On the fastapi documentation it says you can do `uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80` but i was thinking if that is the correct way for production? Do i just enter that command, and will the API automatically start listening on the servers IP address? Also is this method efficient and will it be able to handle all the requests? Or what would i change for it to be faster?
- When should i use a process manager?
- When should i use multiple workers? And what benefits do they provide?
- When should i use Gunicorn as mentioned here? https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/#gunicorn

I am just a little confused on how to deploy this because one article says do this, another says do this.

Comment: Please ask one question per question only and make sure it is related to programming (writing code)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If for whatever reasons you don't like to use Docker-Ce, the best way is to create a `systemd-service` unit for your application so every time it goes down, systemd will try to restart it, then run it with servers like `wgsi` or `gunicorn`.

This link can help about systemd-services too:

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-a-flask-application-as-a-service-with-systemd

P.S note that the way you serve gunicorn isn't really related to docker or systemd-service, for both approaches you need to config gunicorn.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What do you mean by i need to config unicorn? What benefit does configuring it provide? Or what happens if i dont?

Comment: By configuration I mean whether you use docker or systemd-service, you need to pass on options like  amount of workers and so on, probably nginx + systemd-service + gunicron will help ya serve your app the best way possible by the assumption that you don't want to use docker.
check this: https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, for this info. You helped me find my answer. Also if i use nginx i probably dont need a systemd service because nginx would be it.

Comment: You welcome, just remember that nginx will be your web server, you will need to keep your web application alive, sometimes the web application goes down for many reasons, note that you need docker compose  or a systemd-unit with `restart on failure` option.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your Question:

> How can I deploy FastAPI manually on a Ubuntu Server?

You can check out this video tutorial on how to
[Deploy FastAPI on Ubuntu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dh5lzOwyVAY)

The deployment has the following architecture within a single Ubuntu VM.

[image]

As you take a look at the Architectural diagram above for FastAPI Deployment, it shows a single VM deployment.

Within the Ubuntu VM, there are two systemd services namely `caddy.service` and `gunicorn.service` up and running. The `gunicorn.service` runs the FastAPI application and the `caddy.service` exposes the FastAPI application running on Gunicorn as a reverse proxy with the help of `uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker` worker class. In addition to this, our FastAPI communicates to PostgreSQL database server in an asynchronous fashion with the help of [databases](https://github.com/encode/databases) package that provides simple `asyncio` support for PostgreSQL database.